# Unable to download paypal dispute related attachments with Rest API

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Unable to download dispute related attachment via Rest Api

Access token was generated with all the scopes below:
[scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMu6T.png)

I can get disputes using this api endpoint:
https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/:dispute_id

from the response we can see the documents with attachment links:
[messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E45HG.png)

URL to download document:
https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/content/documents/DIS-010-8cd2522d-c20d-4917-a31d-b9683aa14f17/files/1/download

I tried a get request with headers and bearer token in postman

full response:
{"name":"NOT_AUTHORIZED","debug_id":"9911d2bde7adc","message":"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.","details":[{"issue":"NOT_AUTHORIZED","description":"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions."}]}

I am trying to make a downloadable link with this url
https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/content/documents/DIS-010-8cd2522d-c20d-4917-a31d-b9683aa14f17/files/1/download

The response is showing "NOT_AUTHORIZED"

I have checked paypal dispute documentation. There is no clear instruction about downloading any disputes related attachment files.

Comment: Maybe, you don't add some permissions? https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Sandbox-Environment/quot-Authorization-failed-due-to-insufficient-permissions-quot/td-p/1794523

Comment: I have added all necessary scopes. Which permissions you are talking about?